# Настройка полей документа в latex

Tags: latex

Пытаюсь сверстать latex документ в TeXstudio со следующей преамбулой:

```
\documentclass[14pt,russian]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
total={170mm,257mm},left=2cm,right=2cm,
top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines, tabsize=3}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\starsection}[1]{%
    \section*{#1}%
    \NR@gettitle{#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

При просмотре этого документа в pdf поля не настраиваются так, как это описано в \geometry. Отступ сверху равен не 2 см, а не менее чем 5см, другие поля так же не настраиваются корректно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем может быть связана подобная проблема, и как это исправить.

Comment: а вообще неплохо было бы вам ознакомиться с главой «4. поля, размер страницы и прочее» из книги львовского «набор и вёрстка в пакете latex». или с другим подобным детальным описанием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во всем виноват пакет `\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}`: он "сбрасывает" установленные поля. Достаточно его загрузить выше настроек геометрии и все будет работать. Хотя, я не понимаю, зачем Вы его вообще включаете, Вы же эти же настройки применяете как стиль документа `\documentclass[14pt,russian]{extarticle}`.

Чтобы было видно что происходит, я в опции пакета `geomtry` добавил параметры `showframe,showcrop` - это для показа линий обрезки и рамки рабочего поля. Они нужны просто для демонстрации полей и всего остального, что настраиваете через `geometry`. Когда все будет настроено - их нужно убрать. И еще добавил опцию `includeheadfoot=true` - она включает в размеры `total` еще и верхний и нижний колонтитулы. Мне кажется, что без этой опции поля будут слишком маленькими. Если не нужно, тоже просто удалите и посмотрите как будет выглядеть разметка. Еще добавил пакет `\usepackage{lipsum}` - это тоже только для демонстрации, чтобы не выдумывать, какой текст писать в документе.

PS: Вы два раза включаете `\usepackage{indentfirst}`. И он, вроде как, уже вообще не нужен: в современных дистрибутивах его уже внесли в русскую локаль в `babel`.

```
\documentclass[14pt,russian]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage[showframe,showcrop,includeheadfoot=true]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
total={170mm,257mm},left=2cm,right=2cm,
top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
%\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines, tabsize=3}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\starsection}[1]{%
    \section*{#1}%
    \NR@gettitle{#1}%
}
\makeatother


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[2-5]
\end{document}
```